# Why I see that field values of Enum constants do get serialized/deserialized ? In which scenario and what exactly is not serialized in enums?

Tags: java, serialization, enums

[Serialization Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#a6469) (SE8) implies that field values of enum constants are not serialized (as I read it):

> 1.12 **Serialization of Enum Constants**
>   *Enum constants are serialized differently* than ordinary serializable or externalizable objects. The serialized form of an enum constant consists solely of its name; **field values of the constant are not present** in the ***form***.

But I see that they do get serialized/deserialized.

In code below field `public int x = 1234;` of enum constant `INSTANCE` gets serialized/deserialized in two scenarios:

1. *Being set only in constructor* (after `public int x = 1234;`, `setX()` method never called), `x = 1234` is then successfully deserialized.
2. *After constructor I call `setX(7)`*, but that set value (`x=7`) is then successfully deserialized.

So **what exactly and under which scenario does not get serialized/deserialized in enum?** *And what does the term "form" mean* (from the quote above)?

```
enum MyEnum1 {

INSTANCE {
    public int x = 1234;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
};

public abstract int getX();

public abstract void setX(int x);

}

public class AAA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        MyEnum1 obj = MyEnum1.INSTANCE; 
        obj.setX(7);
        System.out.println(obj.getX());
        String fileName = "d:\\del.me";
        int bufSz = 8 * 1024;

        try {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                    new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName), bufSz));
            oos.writeObject(obj);
            oos.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {   }


        MyEnum1 obj1 = null;
        MyEnum1 obj2 = null;
        try {
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                    new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName), bufSz));

            ObjectInputStream ois1 = new ObjectInputStream(
                    new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName), bufSz));

            obj1 = (MyEnum1) ois.readObject();
            obj2 = (MyEnum1) ois1.readObject();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {  }

        // x is restored, either the one set by setX()
        // or the one just set in inline constructor (initializer) without calling setX() 
        System.out.println(obj1.getX());  // 1234 without setX(7), 7 with setX(7)
        System.out.println(obj2.getX());  // 1234 without setX(7), 7 with setX(7)

    }

}
```

P.S. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432528/does-enums-field-have-to-be-serializable) also implies to me that fields inside enum constants don't get serialized:

> As I see it, it doesn't make sense to mark **Enum's field values** as
>   transient or make them implement Serializable, **since they'll never get
>   serialized**, no matter if they're marked as transient or implement
>   Serializable.

But all (non-transient) fields (at least primitive ones) *either within enum constant (like `Color { RED { fields }; }` )* **or within enum but "outside" every separate constant ( `Color { RED { fields }; fields_for_all_constants}` ) do get serialized**, as I see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test is flawed as it assumes deserializing an enum constant results in more than one instance of the enum constant. From [§8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9) of the JLS (**emphasis** mine):

> An enum type has no instances other than those defined by its enum constants. It is a compile-time error to attempt to explicitly instantiate an enum type (§15.9.1).
>
> In addition to the compile-time error, three further mechanisms ensure that no instances of an enum type exist beyond those defined by its enum constants:
>
> - The final clone method in Enum ensures that enum constants can never be cloned.
> - Reflective instantiation of enum types is prohibited.
> - **Special treatment by the serialization mechanism ensures that duplicate instances are never created as a result of deserialization.**

What this means is setting the `x` on `MyEnum1.INSTANCE` changes the value globally, the same as changing state of a "regular" singleton. When you deserialize the constant you *get the same instance that already exists* which means it has the current value of `x`.

A better test would be to serialize the constant in one run of the program then deserialize in the subsequent run. Try the following example:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        var file = Path.of(System.getProperty("user.dir")).resolve("myenum.bin");
        switch (args[0].toLowerCase()) {
            case "save":
                var instance = MyEnum.INSTANCE;
                instance.setValue(10);
                try (var oos = new ObjectOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(file))) {
                    oos.writeObject(instance);
                }
                break;
            case "load":
                try (var ois = new ObjectInputStream(Files.newInputStream(file))) {
                    System.out.println(((MyEnum) ois.readObject()).getValue());
                }
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("expected 'save' or 'load', actual = " + args[0]);
        }
    }

    public enum MyEnum {
        INSTANCE {
            private int value = 5;
            @Override public void setValue(int value) { this.value = value; }
            @Override public int getValue() { return value; }
        };
        public abstract void setValue(int value);
        public abstract int getValue();
    }
}
```

First run `java Main save` to serialize the enum constant to a file. Then execute `java Main load` which will deserialize the enum constant and print the `value`. Despite serializing the enum constant while the `value` was `10` the deserialized instance will have the `value` be `5` (the initial value). This strongly indicates the fields are not serialized along with the enum constant.

---

> As I see my example code is almost exactly like yours, I don't see which difference makes your snippet and mine behave differently...

Your code creates a *single* JVM instance that sets the value, serializes the enum, and then deserializes the enum. Since this all happens in the same JVM the deserialized enum will be the same instance that already existed and had `x` changed.

My code has two modes: "save" and "load".

- "save" creates a JVM instance, sets the `value` of the enum constant, then serializes the enum to a file
- "load" creates a JVM instance and deserializes the enum constant from the file. It does not modify the `value`

The two modes can't happen during a single invocation of the program which means a *different* JVM instance is used for each mode. Because this happens across two different JVM instances the deserialized enum *is not the same instance* that was serialized.

Comment: JVM creats only one Enum per instance +1